# Google map Addlistener to infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Is it possible to add hover event listener to Infowindow of google maps?

The native events that are available

> closeclick, content_changed, domready, position_changed,
>   zindex_changed

I wanted to add hoverOver and HoverOut when the mouse enter Infowindow

Javascript and Jquery suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by using the .on function of jquery.

```
var infoWindowContentExampleStack = [
"<div class='contentInsideMap' value='Go'>Im a text inside the infoWindow </div>"
]

var infoWindowExampleStack = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: infoWindowContentExampleStack
});


$(document).on('mousenter', 'div.contentInsideMap', function() {
    // do something
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', 'div.contentInsideMap', function() {
    // do something
});
```

I wasn't able to test the whole Infowindow but the div I've added in the infowindow is enough trigger.

Answer (score 2):

**Is it possible to add hover event listener to Infowindow of google maps?**

Yes

**How?**

Like this.

```
var infoWindowContentExampleStack = [
"<span id='contentInsideMap' value='Go'>Im a text inside the infoWindow </span>"
]

var infoWindowExampleStack = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: infoWindowContentExampleStack
});

google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindowExampleStack, 'domready', function() {
    document.id("contentInsideMap").addEvent("hover", function(e) {
        e.stop();
        console.log("Yep this event was triggered inside the info!");
    });
});
```

**This is the only solution?**

**Not**, you can add DOM Events directly into Google maps like this

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(infoWindowExampleStack, 'hover', initialize);
```

Take a look, i hope you get the idea

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ethaan but I wasn't able to make your answers work using the two solutions

Comment: @Abz make sense, answer is 4 years old i'm pretty sure Google change the API in this time

Comment: @Ethaan, yes things probably changed over the years. I think your code should work if you change document.id to document.getElementById and addEvent to addEventListener.